# EC2- non responding http requests

Tags: http, node.js, amazon-ec2, firewall

I just installed my node.js app in a windows micro instance with security group quick-start and with http port enabled.

I opened the firewall in the instance and opened port 80, 443 for inbound and outbound both.

In spite of that, my http requests are not being honored by the node.js app.
From log I see that the app is connected to redis and mongo and socket.io is also started.

What's wrong ? why http requests are blocked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem.

I introduced [log4js](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node) and integrated this with express, as,

```
app.use(log4js.connectLogger(logger, { level: log4js.levels.ERROR }));
```

This created the problem. Somehow this was failing. Looks like it works only with DEBUG. After commenting this, it started working. Strange !!

Answer (score 0):

Have you by chance built your app on top of the *Example Webserver* as currently shown on the [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) home page as well? The sample currently looks like so:

```js
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Either way your Node.js server might simply not be listening on the correct port/hostname combination - the *Example Webserver* listens on port 1337 (rather than the regular HTTP port 80) and on localhost only (rather than on the *private/internal IP* address which has been assigned to your EC2 instance) for example.

If these assumptions apply, you could achieve you goal by adjusting the `listen()` statement accordingly, see my answer to the related question [Node.js Amazon EC2 example webserver - no result](https://serverfault.com/a/355390/10305) for an extended discussion, including a couple of variations regarding the flexible use of the [server.listen(port, [hostname], [callback])](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_callback).

Good luck!

Comment: Something else you can try is to just open all ports for 0.0.0.0/0 temporarily to see if the problem is with the security group or if there's a problem with the instance.

Comment: @Steffen, My app is based on express which listens on port 80 only. I tested this locally in my machine and it works just fine. But do not know why it is not working in EC2

Comment: @bwight, I also opened all TCP ports for 0.0.0.0/0. Still it does not respond. I think it may be something to do with windows 2008 firewall setting. initially ping was not working, when I changed some setting in firewall, ping started working. Dont know what's wrong with HTTP?